# Who first defined open sets in terms of neighborhoods?

Tags: general-topology, math-history

One way to define a *topology* for a set (of "points") *X* is to first give a suitable definition of a *neighborhood of $x$*, for any point $x \in X$, and then to define an *open set* as any subset of $X$ that is a neighborhood of all of its elements.  A *topology* for $X$ is then defined as the family of all open subsets of $X$.

I would like to know *who* first proposed *this* particular approach to defining a topology.

(Note that another approach first defines open sets, and then defines neighborhoods in term of open sets.  Yet another approach takes the *closure* of a set as the fundamental definition.  Etc.)

EDIT: The motivation behind this question can be found in this other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404659).  In that question I give a verbatim rendition of a set of axioms defining neighborhoods and then defining open sets in terms of neighborhoods.  I argue that these axioms, as stated, are faulty.  Later (in my answer to the question) I show what I believe is the genesis of the error.  The problem lies in the subtle difference between the following two alternative versions of one of the axioms:

(B$3$) for each $x$, the set of neighborhoods of $x$ is closed under non-infinite intersections;

(B$3^{\prime}$) if $U_1, \dots, U_n$ are neighborhoods of $x$, then $U_1 \cap \dots \cap U_n$ is a neighborhood of $x$;

(Of course, one typically writes *finite* instead of the awkward *non-infinite*, but I've used the latter in (B$3$) to bring out the fact that the axiom applies to the empty intersection as well.  IOW, the axiom implies that, for each $x \in X$, the entire set $X$ is a neighborhood of $x$.)

In fact I've come across even more emphatic versions of (B$3^\prime$):

(B$3^{\prime\prime}$) if $U_1$ and $U_2$ are neighborhoods of $x$, then $U_1 \cap U_2$ is a neighborhood of $x$;

The problem with (B$3^\prime$) and (B$3^{\prime\prime}$) is that they fail to rule out the case in which some $x \in X$ has no neighborhoods at all, which in turn will imply that the entire space $X$ is not open.

My interest in this question is that I have found at least three separate mentions in the literature of the faulty set of axioms, one as recent as 1997.  It appears that this is a case of an error that has been propagated for decades, and I'm curious about its origin.  In fact, it's not hard to imagine a sequence of rewordings $\text{B}3 \to \text{B}3^\prime \to \text{B}3^{\prime\prime}$.

Comment: I suspect that it was the other way around. Neighborhoods were used to define continuity ($\epsilon-\delta$ is essentially about neighborhoods) and somebody saw that you could generalize this to something they called a "topology." So what you really are looking for is who first thought of the "closed/open" definition of "topology."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I'm not asking what was the first approach to defining a topology, but rather who was the one who first proposed the idea of taking neighborhoods as the fundamental definition.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my comment, @kjo. My point is that there wasn't an idea out there in mathematics called "a topology" and somebody came along and said, "Ah, these neighborhoods in metric spaces match that definition." Rather, there was a notion of continuity using neighborhoods, and somebody realized you could generalize that. So whoever first defined "topology" almost certainly was the first person to understand the neighborhood definition in metric spaces.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I think I did understand it, and I think that your guess as to the history is probably correct, but I have seen approaches to topology that begin with *neighborhoods* as the primary *definition* and define open sets in terms of them, and there must have been a *first* person to adopt this particular *expository approach*.  I'm asking who this is.

Comment: How can you define a neighborhood without referring to open sets?

Comment: When Felix Hausdorff defined topological spaces 1914 in his book "Grundzüge der Mengenlehre" (he exactly defined what is now called $T_2$- or Hausdorff spaces), we used neighbourhoods. So as far as I now, the first definition of an (almost) general topolgical space used nhoods and was by Hausdorff.

Comment: @roger: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404659

Comment: @roger: it's what you do when you consider the notion of base and the topology generated by a base.

Comment: @roger You define a neighborhood in terms of a metric. Indeed, I suspect the use of the word "open" in topology comes from the idea of "open interval," which is just a neighborhood on the real line.

Comment: Ok thanks kjo, Martin Argerami and Thomas Andrews.

Comment: My first guess agrees with Martini's comment: Hausdorff.  If a second guess is needed, I suggest Fréchet.

Answer (score 10):

Felix Hausdorff wrote 1914 in his book "Grundzüge der Mengenlehre":

> (A) Jedem Punkt entspricht mindestens eine Umgebung $U_x$; jede Umgebung $U_x$ enthält den Punkt $x$.
>   (B) Sind $U_x$, $V_x$ zwei Umgebungen desselben Punktes $x$, so gibt es eine Umgebung $W_x$, die Teilmenge von beiden ist ($W_x \subseteqq \mathfrak D(U_x, V_x)$).
>   (C) Liegt der Punkt $y$ in $U_x$, so gibt es eine Umgebung $U_y$, die Teilmenge von $U_x$ ist ($U_y \subseteqq U_x$).
>   (D) Für zwei verschiedene Punkte $x,y$ gibt es zwei Umgebungen $U_x, U_y$ ohne gemeinsamen Punkt ($\mathfrak D(U_x, U_y) = 0$).

My translation:

> (A) Each point has at least one neighbourhood $U_x$; each neighbourhood $U_x$ contains $x$.
>   (B) If $U_x$, $V_x$ are two neighbourhoods of the same point $x$, then there is a neighbourhood $W_x$, which is a subset of both ($W_x \subseteqq \mathfrak D(U_x, V_x)$).
>   (C) If $y$ is a point of $U_x$, then there is a neighbourhood $U_y$, which is a subset of $U_x$ ($U_y \subseteqq U_x$).
>   (D) Each two different points $x,y$ have neighbourhoods $U_x$, $U_y$ which do not have a common point ($\mathfrak D(U_x, U_y) = 0$).

As far as I know this is one the earliest definitions of the concept "topological space" (to be exact, of a Hausdorff space due to axiom (D)) and the first which uses neighbourhoods (note: $\mathfrak D$ denotes the intersection herein, it is the first letter of the german "Durchschnitt").

Comment: Note that, because of (C), we have a system of _open_ neighbourhoods that is defined here, so a (base of) open neighbourhoods is the notion that is used as axiomatic. Not the later notion of system of neighbourhoods (as sets that contain an open set around that point).