# The origin of notation Z(f) and U(f) in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, notation

It is common in algebraic geometry to denote a hypersurface $f=0$ in the affine space $\mathbb A^n$ as $Z(f)$  and the complement to the hypersuface by $U(f)$. What is the origin of these notations? I guess that these notations can come from the German language?

Comment: The "Z" most probably stands for "zeros", as $Z(f)$ is the zero set of $f$.

Comment: Perhaps $U$ is for *open*.

Comment: What is the relation between $U$ and open ? On the other hand, this is the first time I see the notation $U(f)$.

Comment: @Cantlog: The $U$ could stand for "Umgebung", which is german, and literally translates as "surrounding" in english.

Comment: @NilsMatthes: thanks !

Comment: @lhf: "$U$ is for *open*" - Great!

Comment: @Cantlog, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520290/why-do-we-traditionally-use-letter-u-for-open-sets.

Comment: Thanks everybody for these comments, this answers my question indeed

Comment: "$U$ is for open". Well yes, why nut?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$Z(f)$ most probably stands for the *zero set* of $f$.

$U(f)$ probably stands for the *open set* of $f$, since $Z(f)$ is closed in the  Zariski topology.

The letter $U$ is commonly used to denote open sets in topology. It seems to come from *Umgebung*, which is *neighbourhood* in German. See [Why do we traditionally use letter U for open sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520290/why-do-we-traditionally-use-letter-u-for-open-sets)