# Why are open sets denoted $U$, $G$, and measurable sets $E$?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, notation, math-history

Why are open sets usually denoted by $U$?
Is there a reference about this?
Sometimes open set uses the letter $G$, such as $G_{\delta} $ set.
I also wonder the meaning of $G$.

Additional question: Why do we use or who first used $E$ to denote a subset in measure theory?

Comment: This is a very good question. My naive guess would be because $U$ will always be the *union* of basic open sets (e.g. open balls)...

Comment: And  why  $F$ is  always used to denote closed sets?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520290/why-do-we-traditionally-use-letter-u-for-open-sets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$U$ stands for Umgebung. Reference: https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umgebung_(Mathematik) This is the German wikipedia article corresponding to Neighborhood.
More complete history on this in [Why do we traditionally use letter U for open sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520290/why-do-we-traditionally-use-letter-u-for-open-sets)

$E$ stands for Ensemble, which is French for set. You can see it used in Lebesgue’s original paper to denote arbitrary measurable sets, so that it became tradition https://fermatslibrary.com/s/on-a-generalization-of-the-definite-integral

Answer (score 2):

For $G_\delta$ set and $F_\sigma$ set, each of this is from german word *Gebiet* and french word *fermé*  respectively.

Comment: Additionally, the $\delta$ is for *Durchschnitt* ("intersection" in German) and the $\sigma$ is for *somme* ("sum"/"union" in French).