# Unfamiliar Symbol in Knopp (Theory of Functions)

Tags: complex-analysis, notation

Knopp likes to use a symbol (presumably a letter in some font?) for regions in his *Theory of Functions*:

[image: unknown symbol]

Can anyone tell me how this is meant to be read? A LaTeX command for it would be a nice bonus, but mostly it actually affects how easily I can learn things if I can't "hear myself think" so to speak.

Comment: Looks like Fraktur `\frak`

Comment: Fraktura capital G seems close. $\mathfrak{G}$ = \ mathfrak { G } Does it name a domain (Gebiet), an open connected set?

Comment: Yes, it does. And also (because of course) soon after making this post, but after a solid hour of reading without much hints, I found a place where he denoted an intersection/small region with a legible fraktur little-$\mathfrak{g}$. Looks like the mystery is solved.

Comment: Cf. [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3028215/why-are-open-sets-denoted-u-g-and-measurable-sets-e)

Comment: Though I would object that $\mathfrak{G}$ does not in fact look all *that* much like the original, but I guess that's just a particularly unfortunate choice of font + a reader who doesn't regularly read German ^.^;

Comment: It looks almost identical to the letter G in [this](https://omniglot.com/writing/fraktur.htm) version of Fraktur (for German).

Comment: There are multiple Fraktur fonts. This one looks like a [Schwabacher](https://www.fontriver.com/font/schwabacher/).