# Is an open set containing the level set the same as a neighborhood of the level set?

Tags: general-topology

Are these two phrases saying the same thing?

An open set $\mathcal{N}$ containing the level set $\mathcal{L}$.

A neighborhood $\mathcal{N}$ of the level set $\mathcal{L}$.

Comment: Sometimes, "neighborhood of something" means "any set containing an open set containing that something". But most commonly,  the interpretation is the one you gave.

Comment: Great, thank you!

Comment: Is disagree with Giuseppe Negro's "most commonly" judgement. A neighborhood is normally not required to be open. If so, one usually says it is an *open neigborhood*. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/157735 . But of course it depends on conventions.